# Python PyPDF2 counting PDF pages in scanned PDF generates Xref table not Zero indexed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I have written a fast script to count the pages in PDF files. However, in some files it cannot be read and it returns an error of Xref table not Zero indexed. Basically when expects an Object Id (5.0) and gets Object Id (4.0) for example. Also I have got with other Object Id like (7.0) and gets Object Id(6.0), etc...

My code is:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from pathlib import Path
import os
import math
import logging

numPages=0
workPath = input ('Please introduce your working directory: ')
print ('Your selected path is ' + workPath)
os.chdir (workPath.encode())
logging.basicConfig(filename='errrors.log', 
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fout= open('PagesCount.txt', 'w',  encoding="utf-8")
path_files = Path(workPath)
for file in path_files.glob('**/*.pdf'):
    page_Count = 0
    try:
        with open(str(file), "br") as PDF:
            try:
                page_Count = PdfFileReader(PDF).getNumPages()
                numPages = numPages + page_Count
                print ('Pages in ' + str(file) + ': ' + str(page_Count) + ' pages')
                fout.write ('Pages in ' + str(file) + ':\t' + str(page_Count) + ' pages\n')
            except:
                print('File {} cannot be read'.format(str(file)))
                logging.error('File cannot be read:\t {}'.format(str(file)))

    except:
        logging.error('File is not processed: {}'.format(str(file)))

print ('Total number of pages:\t' + str(numPages) + ' pages')
fout.write ('Total number of pages:\t' + str(numPages) + ' pages\n')
```

So, it happens that I have to count the pages of many scanned PDF files, and a high % of them, about 80% of them go filtered to the errors file due of the mentioned error above. Is there any way to prevent the Xref table not Zero indexed error?

Thank you.

Comment: If you shared an example file demonstrating the issue, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: For confidentiality reasons I am not able to share a sample file :(
However I was able to solve the problem adding the parameter strict = False. Thank you.

Comment: *"solve the problem adding the parameter strict = False"* - that's good to hear. In your answer, though, you mentioned that that *allows to open a **higher** number of files than before* which seems to indicate that there still are some files that run into the error. If you need help with them, I'm afraid you'll have to share example files.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved part of the issue. Setting the parameter strict to false, and it allows to open a higher number of files than before

Changing this line from:
    page_Count = PdfFileReader(PDF).getNumPages()
to
    page_Count = PdfFileReader(PDF, strict=False).getNumPages()

Comment: I added strict=False like you mentioned and I still go the below error: 
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not find xref table at specified location

any advice?